# Why does this Python 3 code fail to remove Unicode accented characters using str.translate()?

Tags: python, unicode, beautifulsoup

I am trying to normalise accented characters in a string in Python 3 like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os

def process_markup():
    #the file is utf-8 encoded
    fn = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'src.txt') #
    markup = BeautifulSoup(open(fn), from_encoding="utf-8")

    for player in markup.find_all("div", class_="glossary-player"):
        text = player.span.string
        print(format_filename(text)) # Python console shows mangled characters not in utf-8
        player.span.string.replace_with(format_filename(text))

    dest = open("dest.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
    dest.write(str(markup))

def format_filename(s):
    # prepare string
    s = s.strip().lower().replace(" ", "-").strip("'")

    # transliterate accented characters to non-accented versions
    chars_in = "àèìòùáéíóú"
    chars_out = "aeiouaeiou"
    no_accented_chars = str.maketrans(chars_in, chars_out)
    return s.translate(no_accented_chars)

process_markup()
```

The input src.txt file is utf-8 encoded:

```
<div class="glossary-player">
    <span class="gd"> Fàilte </span><span class="en"> Welcome </span>
</div>
<div class="glossary-player">
    <span class="gd"> àèìòùáéíóú </span><span class="en"> aeiouaeiou </span>
</div>
```

The output file dest.txt looks like this:

```
ï»¿<div class="glossary-player">
<span class="gd">fã ilte</span><span class="en"> Welcome </span>
</div>
<div class="glossary-player">
<span class="gd">ã ã¨ã¬ã²ã¹ã¡ã©ã­ã³ãº</span><span class="en"> aeiouaeiou </span>
</div>
```

and I am trying to get it to look like this:

```
<div class="glossary-player">
<span class="gd">failte</span><span class="en"> Welcome </span>
</div>
<div class="glossary-player">
<span class="gd">aeiouaeiou</span><span class="en"> aeiouaeiou </span>
</div>
```

I know there's solutions like unidecode but just wanted to find out what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: There is no "ANSI encoding". Do you mean you get what Windows calls ANSI, i.e. something like [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)? Or do you actually get Unicode back?

Comment: Thanks for the correction - misleadingly, Notepad++ has an "Encode in ANSI" menu option which I was referring to. I don't get Unicode back.

Comment: Really?  Then what's the encoding for `src.txt`, and your Python program?  I would expect errors if you processed accented characters which are not UTF-8.

Comment: `dest.txt` looks like valid UTF-8 which you are viewing using something which is broken or misconfigured.

Comment: How are you viewing the resulting file?

Comment: I'm viewing all using Notepad++ and PyCharm - and I see the same in both before and after.

Comment: @tripleee: you're right, it does look like valid UTF-8 and I get the correct characters if I view it as such, that's why I'm puzzled why it does not translate them - they're the same bytes on input/output, it seems. The src.txt and my script are both UTF-8 - all created using PyCharm with UTF-8 as default encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that, [as triplee suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24099531/543440), the file being interpreted as the wrong encoding.

The data in the file was correct (as shown by a hex dump), but possibly due to the lack of a charset declaration Python did not read it in as utf-8, but as cp1252.

To fix this, it was necessary to explicitly state the encoding when opening the file using Python's open() method, so the line:

`markup = BeautifulSoup(open(fn), from_encoding="utf-8")`

needed to be changed to:

`markup = BeautifulSoup(open(fn, encoding="utf-8"))`

Comment: Also needed `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` as first line of script file to sort out minor outstanding problems

Answer (score 3):

`chars.translate(no_accented_chars)` doesn't modify `chars`. It returns a new string with the translation applied. If you want to use the translated string, save it to a variable (perhaps the original `chars` variable):

```
chars = chars.translate(no_accented_chars)
```

or pass it directly to the `write` call:

```
dest.write(chars.translate(no_accented_chars))
```

Comment: Hehe, I missed that the assignment was missing.

Comment: Perfect answer! :) Ok, that was a typo when pasting just part of the  code. I'll edit the question with the full code, so just an upvote for now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suspect that your HTML file contains something like

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

which basically forces BeautifulSoup to reinterpret the UTF-8 as [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) (or whichever legacy charset you have there; Windows-1252? Shudder).

There is a number of other places you can add a `charset=` attribute to a block of HTML, but this would be the typical culprit.

Comment: This is partially based on [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55256/discussion-between-wojtekd-and-tripleee) from an earlier attempt at an answer of mine.

Comment: Good guess, but the file is an HTML fragment - and it does not have an HTML <head> by design.